# What is wrong in this javascript code about an array?

Tags: javascript

**I am a beginner to javascript and I was learning about an array and coded some but it doesn't display anything on the browser.Can you help?**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <p id="samir"></p>
    <script>
        var names = ["keshab", "kiran", "Pankaj"];
        document.getElementByID("samir").innerHTML = names;
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: getElementByID is wrong, use `getElementById`. Also note such errors are easily traceable on console, so use that.

Comment: Fast and furious @Dij

Comment: the error you made check console, please

Comment: You are missing the Id on the HTML as well.

Comment: Which console shall i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo error in your code :
replace getElementByID by getElementById

Answer (score 0):

you ID wrong like this Id

```js
var names = ["keshab", "kiran", "Pankaj"];
        document.getElementById("samir").innerHTML = names;
```

```html
<html>
<body> 
    <p id="samir"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. The correct method to access an element by its ID is getElementById, with a lowercase "b" in "ById".

Here is the corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <p id="samir"></p>
    <script>
        var names = ["keshab", "kiran", "Pankaj"];
        document.getElementById("samir").innerHTML = names;
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.